# CSS Parent div take 100% of the height but UL won't shrink and scroll

Tags: css, flexbox

I have this html and css which makes all div's inside divide to 100% height.

The below works as required:

HTML

```
<section class="fill-height-or-more">

    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>One</h5>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Two</h5>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Three</h5>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Four</h5>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS

```
.fill-height-or-more {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
  
.some-area {
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: hsla(200, 50%, 65%, 1);
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
}
```

The problem is here.

Further to the above I need to add a title and list which also needs to shrink or expand to it's parent which is .some-area class.

And when too small the UL needs to scroll Y.

So here is what I've done:

HTML

```
<section class="fill-height-or-more">

    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>One</h5>
        <ul style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Two</h5>
        <ul style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Three</h5>
        <ul style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Four</h5>
        <ul style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS

```
.fill-height-or-more {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column; 
}
  
.some-area {
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    background: hsla(200, 50%, 65%, 1);
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
}
```

But the issue with this one is that the UL won't expand 100% of the available space.

How can I fix this? I need the UL height to be responsive.

Comment: Hi! try this .some-area {   display: flex;}

Comment: ul {   margin: 0;    padding: 0;}

Comment: Hi @JaswinderKaur ... that didn't work. The page shows a scrollbar and no scrollbar in the UL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it easily without flex.
Here's the code:
HTML:

```
<section class="fill-height-or-more">

    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>One</h5>
        <ul style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Two</h5>
        <ul style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Three</h5>
        <ul style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  
    <div class="some-area">
        <h5>Four</h5>
        <ul style="height: 100%; overflow: scroll">
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
          <li>list here</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.fill-height-or-more {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.some-area {
    background: hsla(200, 50%, 65%, 1);
    border: 1px dashed yellow;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

JS:

```
let areaNum = document.getElementsByClassName("some-area").length;
for (let area of document.getElementsByClassName("some-area")) {
  area.style.height = 100 / areaNum + "%";
}
```

Note: This code will work with any number of divs (some-areas), not just four;